# Why put functions outside objects?

Tags: javascript

I try to understand the concept of prototyping in JS. I found the following example. I asked myself, if the function is declared outside the object. Does it help to save ressources?

JS

```
 function Animal (name) {
   this.name = name;  
  }
 Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
   console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't have to do with performance or "saving resources". That example shows you can add a method o the animal class using prototype. Relevant: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/

Comment: I think it does, because you declare it once instead of for every instance of Animal.

Comment: You are not putting "functions outside objects". It would be more accurate to say you are putting "prototype method definitions outside the constructor".

Comment: In theory, it saves resources because there's only one instance of the function object.  In theory (again) it's _slower_ because the interpreter has to traverse the prototype chain to find the function rather than seeing it directly on the object.   Personally I find the inability to use privately scoped variables a disadvantage so rarely use this model.

Comment: @Alnitak Time vs. space tradeoff… :)

Comment: It sure does. And it is extremely important when creating Javascript frameworks (or some sort of libraries).

Comment: @Alnitak Also… "privacy" is very overrated IMO. What do you *really* gain by having privately scoped variables? (Not that I necessarily want to reopen this topic here, I've ranted about it enough. I just have to respond since you bring it up.)

Comment: @vothaison what "sure does" what?

Comment: @Alnitak : It sure does help to save resources :) !

Comment: @vothaison that depends on the object.  If it's an object that's only created a few times it barely matters.  If you're going to create thousands, then yeah, it matters.

Comment: @deceze it's a lot easier to reason about the behaviour of code if you can be sure that no external actor can modify the state of your variables.  Apart from that, yeah, maybe you're right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you use a function as a Class in Javascript**. Normally, string or number or other primitive properties are initialized inside the function; and methods go into the prototype (this does help saving resources :) ). Just like your example code.

There are other ways to achieve the same "classy behavior", but using prototype is the most basic way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.
When you declare the method inside object constructor(Animal), it will be written to memory each time we instantiate an object. But if we you prototype property, each instance of Animal will share this method, it would be written to memory only once.

Comment: Which in the vast majority of cases would not matter at all, and would also allow you to use "private" variables declared inside the constructor.

Comment: can you give me a source for that @torazaburo

Comment: A source for which part?